# Rigol DS1052E Oscilloscope acting wierd

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm rather new to electronics, and I'm really in trouble here.

I'm have a bit of a puzzle here, regarding my Rigol DS1052E Oscilloscope.
I'm trying to adjust the probes, but I get a wierd result on channel 1.

For both channels I use the same settings:

- Coupling = DC
- Bandwidth limit = on
- Probe = 10x (Also 10x on the actual probe)
- Digital filter = OFF.

I use the squarewave on the scope as input for both channels, and I use the same (one) probe for both channels.
**Channel 2** gives me the expected squarewave with 3 volt signal.
**Channel 1** however, gives me 1/5 = 600 mV and the signal is nowhere near a squarewave. See attached photos.

Please give me your advice.
If I can assist you with further information, then please feel free to comment regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

**Channel 1:**

[image: photo of oscilloscope screen viewing channel 1]

---

**Channel 2:**

[image: photo of oscilloscope screen viewing channel 2]

---

Images on link with pure DC (3.84V) measured with multimeter:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7SZfQswIltgMkszckpuN2lMaEU

**Channel 1: 3.84V DC**

[image: photo of scope channel 1 with 3.84V DC signal]

---

**Channel 2: 3.84V DC**

[image: photo of scope channel 2 with 3.84V DC signal]

Comment: Hmm, it does look like something really odd is going on there.  Channel 2 signal is 300 mV pk-pk, nice square wave.  Channel 1 is double that with a not insignificant DC offset, and it looks like a cap charging through a resistor.  How do things look with just a constant DC level - both with the probe tip shorted to GND and measuring a battery or similar source?

Comment: Channel 1 looks suspiciously like the probe hasn't been compensated properly. Have you adjusted the capacitance of the probe to get the best result on channel 1?

Comment: That looks like more than probe compensation to me, and I think OP is using the same probe for both channels to try to eliminate any problems with the probe itself.

Comment: @alex.forencich Just uploaded screen dumps as you asked for.

Comment: @helloworld922 Yes I have tried that. But its noway near squarewave.

Comment: @alex.forencich Im using the same probe for both channels for every example.

Comment: That's good; I would have suspected a bad probe if you weren't already doing that.  I'm guessing that for the DC test you hooked both probes up to a battery of some sort?  If you're not seeing the same DC level on both channels, that indicates something is seriously wrong.  I'm not super familiar with these scopes; is there a 'factory reset' button anywhere to reset all of the settings?

Comment: You might also want to look for a self calibration function. Sometimes those are useful in diagnosing these situations

Comment: @alex.forencich Yes its my powersupply set on 3.84 Volt DC. I've already tried factory reset without luck.

Comment: Well, settings and probe have been ruled out. I hate to say it, but I think there is a hardware problem in the channel 1 digitizer or front end circuitry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the conclusion here is a bad scope input.  Probably more likely a front-end problem than a digitizer problem, but it's definitely a hardware issue internal to the scope.  It's not the probe because the same probe works fine on channel 2, and it's not a settings issue as a factory reset has been performed.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on warranty and who owns this, you may need to consult service@rigol.com. with an explanation of two waves , same probe on calibration terminal

Good luck. Looks like front end is partially blown.

Consult manual for self test thru Utility menu

Try 1x switch